# What is a Vowelreuben™ Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Vowelreuben™ Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Vowelreuben™ Words™ | Not Vowelreuben™ Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| beanbag | couch |
| doorknob | torch |
| dungeon | hall |
| felon | crime |
| ghost | spirit |
| horizon | cliff |
| hiccup | cough |
| honest | loyal |
| nougat | munch |
| partnership | partner |
| typhoon | twister |
| typist | quill |

CSV version:

```
Vowelreuben™ Words™, Not Vowelreuben™ Words™
beanbag, couch
doorknob, torch
dungeon, hall
felon, crime
ghost, spirit
horizon, cliff
hiccup, cough
honest, loyal
nougat, munch
partnership, partner
typhoon, twister
typist, quill
```

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

---

**Hint 1:**

> For this puzzle, only "A", "E", "I", "O", and "U" are considered "vowels."

**Hint 2:**

> Vowelreubens™ are like Vowelburgers™ but with add-ons inside.

**Most dictionaries can be used. You can rely on UKACD or SOWPODS.**

Comment: Two ™s? You're very keen on keeping hold of that trademark ;-)

Comment: I wanted to say that rot13(gnxvat gur svefg naq ynfg yrggref, jvgu NAL bs gur vaare ibjryf orgjrra gurz, sbezf n jbeq). But then "spirit" and "partner" would also be Vowelreubens, so that can't be it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Great observation. You're very close but there is more to it than that. There is a reason why "spirit" and "partner" are not Vowelreuben words.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess:

> A Vowelreuben™ Word™ is a word that **(its first letter) + vowel + (its last letter)** is a valid English word for any vowel (i.e. a, e, i, o, u).

Examples:

> **beanbag** is a Vowelreuben™ Word™, and **bag**, **beg**, **big**, **bog**, **bug** are all in UKACD.
> **couch** is not a Vowelreuben™ Word™, as **cah**, **ceh**, **cih**, **coh**, **cuh** are not in UKACD.
> **partner** is not a Vowelreuben™ Word™, as **por** is not in UKACD.

Note that

> While **hun** is not in UKACD, it is in SOWPODS, making **horizon** a Vowelreuben™ Word™.
> On the other hand, **sut** isn't in UKACD or SOWPODS, making **spirit** not a Vowelreuben™ Word™. (**por** mentioned above are not in SOWPODS as well.)

Comment: Great job, you are correct. What did you use to check words in UKACD? The website I used [shows "hun" in both dictionaries](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/match?pat=hun&misp=0&minl=1&maxl=31&sps=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&sbs=&outp=0&dict=0&ent=Search).

Comment: I used [this](https://github.com/rdeits/cryptics/blob/master/raw_data/UKACD.txt) as UKACD, which appears as the second result when googling "UKACD". Maybe I've used an unofficial UKACD...

Comment: They could possibly be different editions.